# How to reuse array of items collection in Ext Js widgets?

Tags: extjs, collections, extjs4, reusability, items

I'm using Ext Js 4.1.1.

In many of the Ext JS widgets I am using, I am required to reuse data. For example, the `items` collection for `buttongroup` in top toolbar may be repeated in menu bar on the left side. For manageability, I should be able to have the array for `items` collection **defined in a separate file** (which could potentially follow the class naming convention for auto loading).

The approach I tried is that I am creating a class that has statics. Each static function returns an array that can be assigned to items collection of the widget. This works but I believe that using a class is an overkill if I can just use an array. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will be useful to create separate objects for storing configuration for toolbars, buttons groups and etc. In the context of the extjs in almost all cases you need not  only manage configuration but also behavior of a component.

The best way for me here - creation of generic/basic predefined classes, where you can state not only configuration but work around the behavior, add you'r custom events and process any unexpected results. After it you can easily reuse and extend it easily.

For instance you have a menu or a toolbar with 3 items A, B, C. For sure you need to know wherever you use it what was clicked (for instance) A, B or C. Creating a class and manages required events you can fire you own events which will tell you what was clicked and it is much easier to use in any context where this component will be used. Add post and pre processing, template methods and etc...

Creating a big file just with configuration is not readable and not extendable, will be a case whre you will need to add functionality and behavior to all such generic components and it will be not easier to do with just arrays or simple configs. Separating even just simple general components having just simple configuration (in the beginning) will bring more expressive in the code structure and readability and in the later time gives you the power to manage it.

Pure configurations can just keep the code accurateness and re-usability but what about behavior for in almost cases you need to control..

The design, maintainability and extensibility  are very important points in every big web-applications and in context of extjs 4.

Comment: for most part of your post you are totally right but that was not the question and will leave the author in his case with a overdedigned solution. Not all fits into classes, some parts are data and should be threaded like that. Buttons cam be such parts and it would be a total overkill to write a class which fire new events for each button. Far better is to follow the MVC approach here wirh the controlpipe. This will leave this wirh far less configurations. The click event ist enough and I can identify the button. Don't get me wrong, basicly you are right but you can't do it all that way

Comment: Talking about data I was about components configuration. For simple plain old buttons, yes I agree that is overkill to create classes.  The example with clicks think is not the best, but the main idea is encapsulation and creation of reusable components.